# Event detection coordinates not updated if transition occurs whilst dragging

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, css-transitions, jquery-ui-draggable

Found an interesting issue that I can't seem to step around.

I'm attempting to drag a box to a droppable div, that transitions in with its parent when draggin commences.

Sequence of Events:

1. Start dragging
2. Draw slides in from bottom of screen containing drop target
3. User moves to drop the draggable onto the droppable
4. Over event fires
5. User drops draggable

Now, most of this is fine, however. I've found that the Over event for a droppable **does not seem to fire** if the transition occurs whilst the user is dragging.

A little bit of investigation showed me that the does fire, but only if the draggable is dragged over the droppables *pre transition* location.

If the transition occurs without the user dragging, everything works as expected.

I've done a mockup of the issue here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRRPWv?editors=1111

Here's the js:

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
  helper:"clone",
  containment:"window",
  start:function(){
    $(".holdingbox").css("bottom", 0);
  },
  stop:function(){
    $(".holdingbox").css("bottom", "-200px");
    up = false;
  }
});
$(".ui-droppable").droppable({
  over:function(){
    $("#status").val("OVER");
  },
  out:function(){
    $("#status").val("NOT OVER");
  }
});
var up = false;
$("#manual").on("click", function(){
  $(".holdingbox").css("bottom", up? "-200px" : 0);
  up = !up;
})
$("#status").val("NOT OVER");
```

and the html:

```
<input type="text" id="status"/>
<a href="#" id="manual">MANUAL TRIGGER</a>
<div class="droppable ui-draggable" style="background-color:green">
</div>

<div class="holdingbox">
  <span style="width:100%; text-align:center; display:inline-block; margin-top: 50px;">
    <span>
    <div class="droppable ui-droppable">
      </div>
      </span>

  </span>
</div>
```

And, for anyone who cares, the CSS

```
.holdingbox{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-200px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#dbeef8;
  transition: bottom 0.2s ease-Out
}

.droppable{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ecff09;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

At this point I would be very happy for a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
$( "draggable Element" ).draggable({ refreshPositions: true });
```

From the jQuery UI draggable docs for the refreshPositions option:

```
If set to true, all droppable positions are calculated on every mousemove.
Caution: This solves issues on highly dynamic pages, but dramatically decreases performance.
```

I spent so long on this...